# Resolve IOptions<T> in Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-configuration

I have a class such as this:

```
public class Test : ITest
{
    public Test(IOptions<CustomSection> settings)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I would like to unit test and just maintain the dependency injection. So to accomplish this I have tried the following:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();

var configurationRoot = builder.Build();

//This is a method that injects various services.
var services = InjectServices();

services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configurationRoot);
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var my service = provider.GetService<ITest>();
```

However, I get the following error:

> Unable to resolve servifor type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Test]' while attempting to activate 'Test'.

How can I add IOptions to injection? I thought that `services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configurationRoot);` would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to. Also, my configuration is correct, if I use the same appsettings in my main project, there is no problems.

Comment: fyi: When you're using an IoC container in your test project, It's **not** an unit test anymore. Unit Tests should be isolated from the rest of your system and where external dependencies are used, you should use mocks (i.e. with Moq framework). On top of that, you can directly create an instance of an options object via `Options.Create<TOptions>(new TOptions());` which is more suitable for a **UNIT** test

Comment: Thanks. This is not for a unit test. I put that in title to keep things simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to register services required for using options:

```
// extension method defined in Microsoft.Extensions.Options
services.AddOptions();
```

Also, you should setup how to build `CustomSection` from configurations by something like this:

```
services.Configure<CustomSection>(configurationRoot);
```

Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration)

Reference [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: After adding that, it crashes now due to not any of the fields getting populated. I look at my object that is meant to be filled with data from appsettings, and everything in it is null. Am I missing something else?

Comment: @Bojan you also should configure how to build it from configurations  by something like this: `services.Configure<CustomSection>(configurationRoot);`

Comment: You may find this article useful: [Easy-Configuration-Binding-in-ASPNET-Core](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Dec/12/Easy-Configuration-Binding-in-ASPNET-Core-revisited)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot about that. Thank you. Can you also add that as part of the answer? `services.Configure<CustomSection>(configurationRoot);`